# File contents into an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How would I go about adding each individual word from a text file into an array using javascript?

The file is not a csv and contains about 5 lines each with around 5 words. I know that I'll have to use `.split(" ")` however because there are multiple lines I'm not sure about the loop.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the mentioned text.

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: You could try something along the lines of `var wordArray = []; String(fileData).split('\n').forEach(function(line, i){line.split(' ').forEach(function(word, i){wordArray.push(word)}))`

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi in the JS: var w; function openFile(url) {
      w = window.open();
      w.location = url;
      }                                                                                                                In the html: <p>Filename: <input id = "url" name="url" size=10 type="Text"/></p>
      <a href="javascript:openFile(document.getElementById('url').value)">Open document</a></br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply read the text in a file and then use the following split:

```
split(/\s+/);
```

`\s` matches both spaces and newlines.

Comment: Thanks this was useful

Answer (score 0):

First: define a function to handle the content of the file

```
function parseTheFileContent(fileData)
{
    var lines = fileData.split('\n');

    // do something with the lines array
}
```

Second: make an ajax call to fetch the file content

```
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

if (!httpRequest) return;

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
{
   if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
     if (httpRequest.status === 200) parseTheFileContent(httpRequest.responseText);
   }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it. This helped me out